# Some static files are throwing 404 when deploying Django on vercel

Tags: django, deployment, vercel, django-staticfiles

I am deploying my Django project on vercel

This is my `vercel.json` file

```
{
"version": 2,
"builds": [
    {
        "src": "event_management/wsgi.py",
        "use": "@vercel/python",
        "config": {"maxLambdaSize": "15mb", "runtime": "python3.9"}
    },
    {
        "src": "build_files.sh",
        "use": "@vercel/static-build",
        "config": {
            "distDir": "staticfiles_build"
        }
    }
],
"routes": [
    {
        "src": "/static/(.*)",
        "dest": "/static/$1"
    },
    {
        "src": "/(.*)",
        "dest": "event_management/wsgi.py"
    }
]
```

}

my `settings.py`

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles_build', 'static')
```

everything works fine but when I open the admin panel one CSS file `static/admin/css/base.css` is throwing 404 error all the other static files are loading fine

Here is the [admin panel](https://events-sathyabama-backend-git-main-eventssathyabama.vercel.app/adminpanel/) link.

the base.css is even listed in Vercel static Assets
[image]

You can also check the file is present on the directory listing [here](https://events-sathyabama-backend-git-main-eventssathyabama.vercel.app/static/admin/css)

here is my github repo [link](https://github.com/Events-Sathyabama/Events-Sathyabama) the code is in main branch

Answer (score 0):

After inspecting the logs and the files present, I can see all works fine, the css file for the `base.css` for the admin panel returned a response `300`.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0vu8.png)

So, the solution is all good.

just incase you left it out, it will good to install and configure [white noise](https://whitenoise.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).